# What is the problem with this code? It never ends (Top View of a Binary Tree)

Tags: c++, error-handling, tree, binary-tree

**Problem Statement** : Print the Top view of the binary tree

**My approach** : I maintain a queue which has a pair inside it each for `root->data` and `horizontal distance(hd)`. I push the root with the `hd` in the queue and add it to the `map` which contains the `hd` and the `root->data`. Then I pop from the queue. Now, if there are any children of the popped root, I insert them into the queue and the above procedure keeps on happening until the queue is not empty.

**My code :-**

```
void topView(Node * root) {
        queue<pair<int, int>> q;
        map<int, int> m;
        q.push({root->data, 0});
        while(q.empty() == false){
            int node_val = q.front().first;
            int hd = q.front().second;
            m[hd] =node_val;
            q.pop();
            if(root->left){
                int hdl = hd -1;
                q.push({root->left->data, hdl});
            }
            if(root->right){
                int hdr = hd + 1;
                q.push({root->right->data, hdr});

            }


        }
        for(auto i=m.begin();i!=m.end();i++) 
        { 
            cout<<i->second<<" "; 
        } 
    }
```

**ERROR : ** Time limit exceeding(That is the code doesn't stop running)
**NOTE** : Also, I found that I'm unable to update the `horizontal distance(hd)` properly in my code for every node. And I can't add `hd` as a member of Node class, so I have to fit it inside this function itself and I can't figure it out a way to do it.(`hdl` and `hdr`)
Please help and give some corrections to the code.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `m[hd] =node_val;` -- This will not work the you way you intended if the binary has duplicate data.  Does the binary contain duplicates?

Comment: No, it doesn't contain duplicates

Comment: Why a pointer when a `const` reference would do?

Comment: I am surprised that `root` is never updated in the process. This implies that `root->left` will stay true ...

Comment: What if `root` is null?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add `root==NULL`, but for the test case which I was testing this code, the root wasn't NULL. Please tell me why this code is not ending.

Comment: If `root->left` or `root->right` is non-null on the first iteration, they're probably going to stay non-null until the end of time – you forgot to traverse the tree. This sounds like it should be an in-order traversal, of which there are many examples online and in the literature.

Comment: As @Damien says you don't update root so root->left and root->right won't change ever and you will endlessly push nodes into the queue.

Comment: Yeah.. the root isn't changing. Thanks @Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code. One is that you're only storing the node values in the queue instead of the node pointers. So your traversal condition

```
if(root->left)
```

is only checking for the children of the root node. This leads to an infinite loop because we are not traversing past the root node.
The second issue is even if we traversed correctly, the top view logic is not using the map correctly.

```
m[hd] = node_val
```

Since this is overwriting for each hd, this will give you the bottom view. We want the first occurence for each hd here. I have updated the code.

```
void topView(Node * root) {
        queue<pair<Node*, int>> q;
        map<int, int> m;
        q.push({root->data, 0});
        while(q.empty() == false){
            Node* current_node = q.front().first;
            int node_val = current_node->data;
            int hd = q.front().second;

            if(m.find(hd) == m.end())
                m[hd] =node_val;

            q.pop();
            if(current_node->left){
                int hdl = hd -1;
                q.push({current_node->left, hdl});
            }
            if(current_node->right){
                int hdr = hd + 1;
                q.push({current_node->right, hdr});

            }


        }
        for(auto i=m.begin();i!=m.end();i++) 
        { 
            cout<<i->second<<" "; 
        } 
    }
```